# Is it possible to run kafka in spring boot with only kafka-client, e.g. without spring-kafka?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams, spring-kafka

I am creating a kafka streams api application in spring boot and I don't want to use spring-kafka dependency. Is it possible to use only apache kafka with "kafka-client" dependency?

Placing my kafka code in a @Component in spring boot and running it results in StreamsBuilderFactoryBean not found error every time, unless I include spring-kafka dependency.
What am I doing wrong? Is my approach even correct? (new to kafka and spring) :)

Any guidance is welcome!

Comment: Why use spring, then, if you aren't going to use its features? The short answer is that you can use any Java library in Spring, but it wouldn't be managed in the Spring lifecycle, so you'd need to hook that up yourself and not use Components/Beans for those parts

Comment: I still need to use DI and actuator in my application so that's why. I am thinking about using spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka to solve the lifecylcle issue qith streambuilder. Would you recommend that over spring-kafka for my case?

Comment: AFAIK, `cloud-stream-binder-kafka` has a dependency on `spring-kafka`

Comment: Ok, I guess I'll have to use spring - kafka then.

Comment: Thank you for the help, it was/is a bit confusing :)